# How to Host ASP.Net Core API in cPanel?

Tags: asp.net-core, cpanel

How to Host ASP.Net Core API application in cPanel. Please explain step by step

Answer (score 3):

You can use the WHM plugin called NexusCore
See https://nexuscore.io/
They have a freemium license for up to 5 accounts.

Comment: NexusCore has been deprecated. https://nexuscore.io/nexuscore-deprecation-notice

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel? Does your hosting provider support .NET Core? You might need to check it with them first. If you are using Windows platform and use Plesk control panel, you can use Webdeploy to publish it, you can read this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/